# How to Set up a LAN Connection consisting of 3 computers running CentOS6.3 Operating System

Tags: centos6

I have 3 computers and all have centos version 6.3. Now I want to set up "LAN
Connection" between these 3 computers. But nothing happened and no help found 
regarding   "Setting Up Lan consisting three or more computers running
centOS6.3".

I have changed my host name as mac1, mac2 and mac3 and their corresponding static ip address is 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.30 and 192.168.1.50. Now if I deploy a application on tomcat server in mac1 system and when try to access this application from browser of mac2 system by typing this address "http://192.168.1.30:8657/One"  then error comes "OOPS Object not found".
here 192.168.1.30 is ipaddress of mac1 in which application has deployed 8657 is port no tomcat of mac1 and One is application name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to ping each other from each hosts, there is no issue in LAN connection.

Actually, your error message `OOPS Object not found` is not likely a LAN related issue.

It is better to check your tomcat logs in `192.168.1.30`